# insert SRID on the_geom field using shapely

Tags: python, geo, shapely

I have a column in my db, called the_geom a geometry type and i set the srid as 4326 of sql alchemy,

when i try to insert a wkt Polygon in this field, they give me this error :

```
DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)
```

i using shapely to get a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error message as you and solved the problem by wrapping the wkt of the Polygon in a ST_GeomFromText.

Example on PostGIS DB:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO a_table (the_geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(%(polygon)s, 4326))",
    {'polygon': polygon.wkt}
)
```